# How to preserve uppercase styling in form when user get a copy by email and PDF generated in wp Fluent Form

Tags: javascript, forms, uppercase

I have a contact form made with the Fluent Form WordPress plugin.
The Form has the option to text-transform to uppercase. So it's all look good to the user; however, when an email notification and a PDF generated is sent to the user after form submission, it is all in lowercases.

How can I keep the input data in uppercase in email and PDF doc?

There is an option to add custom CSS and JS.
For JS, it says

> Custom Javascript
>
> Your additional JS code will run after this Form is initialized. Would you please provide a valid javascript code? Invalid JS code may
> break the Form.
>
> The Following Javascript variables are available that you can use:
> $form: The Javascript (jQuery) DOM object of the Form

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone is looking for a solution. this one is working for me.

```
        $(function() {
            $('input').keyup(function() {
                this.value = this.value.toLocaleUpperCase();
            });
        });
```

source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-input-characters-to-upper-case-while-typing-using-css-jquery/